# How does one determine if iODBC, unixODBC (or neither) are installed?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, unixodbc, iodbc

I'm on Ubuntu Linux and wondering how to detect what ODBC driver manager the system has, if any.

Like Rakib's commentary, one very rough way I've used is to simply try and run `isql` (unixODBC) or `iodbctest`, because Ubuntu will report whether their parent package is installed. What's interesting is that on this fresh VM, pyodbc tells me that unixODBC was used even though its tools are not installed (see screenshot).

[image: Running isql, iodbctest, and pyodbc.connect() to determine what ODBC driver manager is available]

Comment: dpkg-query -L unixODBC ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Ideally: detect the ODBC driver manager so that shell scripts can utilize the appropriate logic for those subtle differences between the two.

Answer (score 1):

this is a crude way to do it by works:

```
find / -name "*unixodbc*"
```

Answer (score 1):

> To verify whether unixODBC is installed in the system, you can run the commands `which odbcinst` and `which isql`, which should return the path to the corresponding tools, or just run `isql`, which should print the syntax and available options for the isql utility.

[Installing and Configuring an ODBC Driver on Linux (DEB / RPM)](https://blog.devart.com/installing-and-configuring-odbc-driver-on-linux.html)